# How to use dynamic data structures with GORM

Tags: go, go-gorm

We are developing a multi-tenant application with Go backend.
We use Gorm as ORM library.

In some cases we have to assign some custom fields to certain users, so different structs for user X and user Y.

Is it possible to make structs dynamic?

Comment: No it's not possible, Go is a statically typed language. However, if you need to provide custom fields for a struct type you could have it have a field of type map/slice of CustomField...

Answer (score 0):

static language golang doesn't support dynamic struct.
Instead,
I sugguest using a higher struct User containing all fields X and Y both have.
Besides,
Whether to design a bigger struct or different structs  depends on your db model. If there is only one table in the database t_user, one model is good. If there are two or more tables like t_X ,t_Y, apparently you should design two or more models.